# jq update key and value with help of variables

Tags: json, unix, jq

I need to update JSON data with the given key and value. I tried passing this as variables for both key and value. 
I have JSON data, in my Unix method, I get key and value as parameters. I need to update the JSON data for that key with the given value.

Comment: For the same case, based on the flag I might have to even add to the existing JSON data with the given key value.

Comment: Do you have an example json you want to update and the key and value parameters you expect to update with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just updating a property by name somewhere in an object and how complex you expect to set the key, you could obtain all paths to values in your tree and compare to set your value.

```
$ jq --arg key 'somekey' --arg value 'somevalue' 'reduce (paths | select(.[-1] | tostring == $key)) as $i (.;
    setpath($i; $value)
)' input.json
```